# How can i apply cell format dynamically by columns name?

Tags: php, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

good day, my current problems here is to apply date and decimal format based on columns name.

`

```
            //Date Format
            new \Google\Service\Sheets\Request([
                "repeatCell" => [
                    "range" => [
                        "sheetId" => $sheet_id,
                        "startColumnIndex" => 1,
                        "endColumnIndex" => 3,
                    ],
                    "cell" => [
                        "userEnteredFormat" => [
                            "numberFormat" => [
                            "type" => "DATE",
                            "pattern" => "dd-mm-yyyy"
                            ]
                        ]
                    ],
                    "fields" => "userEnteredFormat.numberFormat",
                ],
            ]),

            //Decimal Format
            new \Google\Service\Sheets\Request([
                "repeatCell" => [
                    "range" => [
                        "sheetId" => $sheet_id,
                        "startColumnIndex" => 2,
                        "endColumnIndex" => (sizeof($this->dataCols->all())),
                    ],
                    "cell" => [
                        "userEnteredFormat" => [
                            "numberFormat" => [
                            "type" => "NUMBER",
                            "pattern" => "#,##0.00"
                            ]
                        ]
                    ],
                    "fields" => "userEnteredFormat.numberFormat",
                ],
            ]),
```

`

I already figure it out based on column range. My real question is which part do i need to modified to apply cell format based on column name? Thank you.

The sample:

[image: date]

This is date columns.

[image: ammount]

This is Amount column.

i have alots of columns name that goes by default datatype.Currently, i set the format based on range, for examples like setIndexColumns =>0, endIndexColumns =>3, . How do i set the datatype format by columns name? for examples, if the columns name Doc. Date, the whole column or the data will be shown as date format. if the columns name Amount(MYR), the whole column or data will be shown as decimal format.

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot imagine your situation. About `My real question is which part do i need to modified to apply cell format based on column name?`, can you provide the sample input and output situations you expect? By this, I would like to try to understand your question.

Comment: Hi @Tanaike , oh okay ill provide the sample input and output in the question above.

Comment: Thank you for replying and adding more information. Your header row is the 1st row of the sheet? And, your expected column titles are `Doc. Date` and `Amount (MYR)`? In this case, the space is included in the column title? I deeply apologize that I'm trying to correctly understand your question.

Comment: You are welcome Mr @Tanaike `Your header row is the 1st row of the sheet?`, no its on the 3rd row of the sheets. `your expected column titles are Doc. Date and Amount (MYR)? ` yes it is. `the space is included in the column title?` what do you mean by space? because if i not mistaken, i did not put any space in the column title.

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `no its on the 3rd row of the sheets.`, in your situation, you want to set the number format from row 3 to last row? About `what do you mean by space?`, for example, `Doc. Date` includes a space of ` ` between `Doc.` and `Date`. When you want to use the column title, I thought that the correct column title is required to be used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to set the number format to the columns by searching the column title. The request body of the number format is shown in your script.
- In your Spreadsheet, the header row is row 3. And, you want to set the number format from row 3 to the last row.
- You want to achieve this using googleapis for PHP.
- You have already been able to get and put values to Google Spreadsheet using Sheets API.

In this case, I thought that the following flow is required to be done.

1. Retrieve the header row (In your situation, it's row 3.).
2. Create the request body by searching the column using the header title.
3. Request Sheets API using the created request body.

When this flow is reflected in the sample script, it becomes as follows.

#### Sample script:

```php
$service = ###; // Please use your client.
$spreadsheet_id = "###"; // please set Spreadsheet ID.
$sheet_name = "Sheet1"; // Please set the sheet name.
$sheet_id = "###"; // Please set the sheet ID of the sheet name.

// Object for searching the header title. This is from your showing script.
$obj = [
    "Doc. Date" => ["numberFormat" => ["type" => "DATE", "pattern" => "dd-mm-yyyy"]],
    "Amount (MYR)" => ["numberFormat" => ["type" => "NUMBER", "pattern" => "#,##0.00"]]
];

// Retrieve the header title.
$res1 = $service->spreadsheets_values->get($spreadsheet_id, "'" . $sheet_name . "'!A3:3");
$header = $res1["values"][0];

// Create a request body for batchUpdate.
$requests = [];
foreach ($header as $i => $h) {
    if (array_key_exists($h, $obj)) {
        array_push($requests, 
            new \Google\Service\Sheets\Request([
                "repeatCell" => [
                    "range" => [
                        "sheetId" => $sheet_id,
                        "startColumnIndex" => $i,
                        "endColumnIndex" => $i + 1,
                        "startRowIndex" => 3,
                    ],
                    "cell" => ["userEnteredFormat" => $obj[$h]],
                    "fields" => "userEnteredFormat.numberFormat",
                ],
            ]),
        );
    };
}

// Request Sheets API using the created request body.
if (count($requests) > 0) {
  $batchUpdateCellFormatRequest = new \Google\Service\Sheets\BatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest(["requests" => $requests]);
  $service->spreadsheets->batchUpdate($spreadsheet_id, $batchUpdateCellFormatRequest);
};
```

- When this script is run, the header title is retrieved from row 3, and create a request body using the header title and object. And, request Sheets API using the request body.

#### Note:

- If your actual header titles are different from `$obj`, please modify them for your actual header title.

#### References:

- [Method: spreadsheets.values.get](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/get)
- [Method: spreadsheets.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/batchUpdate)

Comment: Oh my days! Once again, you're the masterpiece Mr @Tanaike, i am really bad that i cant figure it out using `foreeach`. Thank you Mr @Tanaike. Have a good day!

Comment: @benzi Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.